# Why does Firebase trigger a child_added event for an update operation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering about the behaviour of the Firebase Realtime database in the following situation. (Note: Since my production version has too many rules and code I've created a minimal version where I can reproduce the behaviour in case you are wondering about my strange security rules)

**SDK:** `Firebase JavaScript SDK: 7.19.1`

**Code:**
*Stays the same for both versions*

```js
const database = firebase.database();
const allUsersRef = database.ref("users");
const myUserRef = database.ref("users/1");

allUsersRef.on("child_added", (data) => {
  console.log("child_added", data.val());
});

allUsersRef.on("child_changed", (data) => {
  console.log("child_changed", data.val());
});

allUsersRef.on("child_removed", (data) => {
  console.log("child_removed", data.val());
});

myUserRef
  .update({
    name: "John",
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("update success");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("update error", error);
  });
```

---

#### Version 1

**Security rules:**

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$userId": {
        ".write": false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Console output**
[image: Console output - Version 1]

---

#### Version 2

**Security rules:**

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    ".read": false
  }
}
```

**Console output**
[image: Console output - Version 2]

---

**In both version nothing is ever written to the Firebase database because the security rules will not allow this.**

Two things I don't understand here:

1. I know from [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html) that the Firebase Realtime database operations are optimistic which explains why `child_added` is displayed in the console even though it's never written to the database. But what I don't understand is why a `child_added` event is triggered and not a `child_changed` event because it's an `update` operation and not a `set` operation.
2. Why is the behaviour different based on my security rules even though the Firebase operations are optimistic and in both versions nothing is written to the database? I would have expected the same console output.

Comment: Note: Added an extra question for the 2nd one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63727336/2416687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Firebase trigger a child_added event for an update operation?

From the flow in your first screenshot it looks like `/users/1` doesn't exist yet, which means that node is created optimistically client-side. This happens regardless on the type of write operation you perform in your code: the behavior is based on the transformation on the database, and not on the API call.

Comment: The entry does not yet exist. That explains it, thank you.

Comment: I'm curious if you have an idea about my other question.

Comment: Not yet, I was still thinking about that one. Given that I was able to answer #1 without answering #2 though, you really should post them as separate questions.

Comment: Added a new question for the second one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63727336/2416687