# Firebase Realtime database listeners behave differently depending on the security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently getting an unexpected behaviour from the Firebase Realtime database. To reproduce it I've used exactly the code below only using the Firebase JavaScript SDK (`7.19.1`) with Vanilla JS.

**Code:**
*Stays the same for both versions.

Only the security rules will be changed directly in Firebase.*

```js
const CONFIG = { ... };  // TODO insert your config
const AUTH_TOKEN = "eyJ0..."  // TODO insert your auth token (JWT)

firebase.initializeApp(CONFIG);

firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("authentication successful");
    performFirebaseOperations();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("authentication failed", error);
  });

const performFirebaseOperations = () => {
  const database = firebase.database();
  const allUsersRef = database.ref("users");
  const myUserRef = database.ref("users/1");

  allUsersRef.on("child_added", (data) => {
    console.log("child_added", data.val());
  });

  allUsersRef.on("child_removed", (data) => {
    console.log("child_removed", data.val());
  });

  myUserRef
    .update({
      name: "John",
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("update success");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("update error", error);
    });
};
```

---

#### Version 1

**Security rules:**

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$userId": {
        ".write": false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Console output:**

[image]

---

#### Version 2

**Security rules:**

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    ".read": false
  }
}
```

**Console output:**
[image]

---

**In both version nothing is ever written to the Firebase database because the security rules will not allow this.**

[This article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/what-happens-to-database-listeners-when-security-rules-reject-an-update.html) explains that the Firebase Realtime database operations are optimistic which explains why `child_added` is displayed in the console even though it's never written to the database. From my understanding *Version 1* is the expected behaviour. But why doesn't *Version 2* show the same behaviour even though I've only changed the security rules? I thought the update is optimistic without going to the server first, so I expected a `child_added` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, but it's another edge case.

I was able to get the same result with the rules that allow writing, by making the client go offline before any other operation.

```
firebase.database().goOffline();
```

At that point the behavior with your first set of rules is the same as with the second set of rules.

My testbed, although you won't be able to change my rules: https://jsbin.com/guzowak/edit?js,console

Given this...

---

It comes down to a guarantee that the Firebase client makes to never show you a partial snapshot.

In your first case the flow is as follows:

1. Your client listens to `/users` (for both `child_added` or `child_removed`, but either of them would be enough for this step), so it gets a snapshot of the data for all users.
2. You then perform a write to `/users/1`, which is a modification of a node the client already knows, so it can fire a local event for that change.

In your second case, the client never gets the data for `/users` in step 1, so it can't fire the event in step 2.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't get any console output if I uncomment the `goOffline` part. I've also tried it with my version and my console only outputs "authentication successful" and no other operations. But I think that is what you mean? That the operation does nothing.

Comment: If I change the `update` operation to a `set` operation with the offline version I'm getting the same output (Only a `child_added` event). I think I understand it now because Firebase has a local version of the database on the client side and in this local version the path for "users" doesn't exist and therefore it can't update something here if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that last statement is indeed the gist of it. And sorry for not realizing that a `set()` would fix it, as that indeed solves the problem. From a `set()` the client can guarantee that this is now the complete value of the node. For such a small API, the Realtime Database has a lot of niche behavior. :)